# Swift 2.0 Subscript issues with Dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, option-type, subscript

I've looked at the other questions on here about subscripting with dictionaries and I didn't see anything that quite fit what my scenario is. It may be that I'm still too new to Swift to realize it but in any case here is my scenario. I'm getting the typical can't "Subscript" dictionary with type string. I've seen the posts on here about it being an optional and needing to unwrap it however when I try that, Xcode suggests that I remove the !, so I do that, then I get the subscript error.

I've watched tons of tutorials on swift development and a lot of them use playgrounds and I never remembered seeing anyone have to do this in any of the tutorials. So I tried the same thing in a playground and it worked.

Here is what I have in the ViewController that DOESN'T work.

```
 var validFields:Dictionary = ["loanBalanceInput":false,"cashOutInput":false,"appraisedValueInput":false,"interestRateInput":false]  

func validationSuccess(sender:UITextField){
            sender.backgroundColor = green
        switch sender {
            case loanBalanceInput:
                validFields["loanBalanceInput"] = true
               break
          default:
            break
    }
}
```

What I've done is create a dictionary of strings that refer to textfields and their validation status to track whether or not they have been validated. The concept is that when everything in the dictionary is true, I can activate the calculate button.

However I get the "cannot subscript a value of type dictionary with an index of type string" error... However this code in a playground works...

```
 var validatedFields:Dictionary = ["loanBalanceInput":false,"cashOutInput":false,"appraisedValueInput":false,"interestRateInput":false]
 validatedFields["loanBalanceInput"]
 validatedFields["loanBalanceInput"] = true
```

I don't understand what's going on here. Is it because this is an optional?

```
@IBOutlet weak var loanBalanceInput: UITextField!
```

I'm not unwrapping it in my switch? I'm not trying to get at the value of loanBalanceInput though, I'm just checking to see if it was the sender.

Comment: Normally a dictionary declaration needs also the type of the containing keys and values like `var validFields:Dictionary<String,Bool> = ...` but as the compiler can infer the type just delete the annotation.

Comment: Oh, WTF. I'm an idiot. I still don't get why it works in playgrounds but that's not really the issue. I let it infer type and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to add your suggestion as an answer, I can accept it. Thx.

Comment: you're welcome, I did it

Answer (score 0):

Normally a Swift `Dictionary` declaration needs also the type of the containing keys and values like

```
var validFields: Dictionary<String,Bool> = [" ...
```

but as the compiler can infer the type just delete the annotation.